# Using INotifyPropertyChanged with Entity Framework 6 DbContext Generator

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, inotifypropertychanged

I know I can use ObjectContext instead, but I like the features of DbContext / DbSet. My application isn't large enough to warrant me writing complex view models, so I'd like to implement change notification on the EF generated models directly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by replacing the default T4 template (the .tt file automatically added by Entity Framework) with the following, then right clicking the .tt file and selecting "Run Custom Tool".

Important: This will regenerate your models which will cause any customizations to be discarded. I recommend you implement your customizations via the template rather than modifying the model class directly to prevent this from being a problem in the future.

Note: Replace `string inputFile = @"MessageLog.edmx";` with the name of your edmx file.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
 output extension=".cs"#><#

CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this, 1);
MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);

string inputFile = @"MessageLog.edmx";
EdmItemCollection ItemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();

EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
WriteHeader(fileManager);

foreach (var entity in ItemCollection.GetItems<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
#>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#> : INotifyPropertyChanged<#=code.StringBefore(", ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
<#
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity && p.DefaultValue != null);
    var collectionNavigationProperties = entity.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == entity && np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
    var complexProperties = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == entity);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || collectionNavigationProperties.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    public <#=code.Escape(entity)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#> = <#=code.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new ObservableListSource<<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(complexProperty)#> = new <#=code.Escape(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>
    }

<#
    }

    var primitiveProperties = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == entity);
    if (primitiveProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var edmProperty in primitiveProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, edmProperty);
        }
    }

    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach(var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, complexProperty);
        }
    }

    var navigationProperties = entity.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == entity);
    if (navigationProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            WriteNavigationProperty(code, navigationProperty);
        }
    }
#>

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
}
<#
    EndNamespace(namespaceName);
}

foreach (var complex in ItemCollection.GetItems<ComplexType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(complex.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(namespaceName, code);
#>
using System;

<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#>
{
<#
    var complexProperties = complex.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == complex);
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = complex.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == complex && p.DefaultValue != null);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    public <#=code.Escape(complex)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#> = <#=code.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(complexProperty)#> = new <#=code.Escape(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>
    }

<#
    }

    var primitiveProperties = complex.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType && p.DeclaringType == complex);
    if (primitiveProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach(var edmProperty in primitiveProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, edmProperty);
        }
    }

    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach(var edmProperty in complexProperties)
        {
            WriteProperty(code, edmProperty);
        }
    }
#>
}
<#
    EndNamespace(namespaceName);
}

if (!VerifyTypesAreCaseInsensitiveUnique(ItemCollection))
{
    return "";
}

fileManager.Process();

#>
<#+
string GetResourceString(string resourceName)
{
    if(_resourceManager == null)
    {
        _resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("System.Data.Entity.Design", typeof(System.Data.Entity.Design.MetadataItemCollectionFactory).Assembly);
    }

    return _resourceManager.GetString(resourceName, null);
}
System.Resources.ResourceManager _resourceManager;

void WriteHeader(EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager)
{
    fileManager.StartHeader();
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// <#=GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1")#>
//
// <#=GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2")#>
// <#=GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3")#>
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<#+
    fileManager.EndBlock();
}

void BeginNamespace(string namespaceName, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceName))
    {
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(namespaceName)#>
{
<#+
        PushIndent(CodeRegion.GetIndent(1));
    }
}


void EndNamespace(string namespaceName)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceName))
    {
        PopIndent();
#>
}
<#+
    }
}

void WriteProperty(CodeGenerationTools code, EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    WriteProperty(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
                  code.Escape(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
                  code.Escape(edmProperty),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
}

void WriteNavigationProperty(CodeGenerationTools code, NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
{
    var endType = code.Escape(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    WriteProperty(PropertyVirtualModifier(Accessibility.ForProperty(navigationProperty)),
                  navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ObservableListSource<" + endType + ">") : endType,
                  code.Escape(navigationProperty),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navigationProperty)),
                  code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navigationProperty)));
}

void WriteProperty(string accessibility, string type, string name, string getterAccessibility, string setterAccessibility)
{
#>
    private <#=type#> _<#=name#>;
    public <#=type#> <#=name#>
    {
        <#=getterAccessibility#>get { return _<#=name#>; }
        <#=setterAccessibility#>set
        {
            if (_<#=name#> != value)
            {
                _<#=name#> = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("<#=name#>");
            }
        }
    }
<#+
}

string PropertyVirtualModifier(string accessibility)
{
    return accessibility + (accessibility != "private" ? " virtual" : "");
}

bool VerifyTypesAreCaseInsensitiveUnique(EdmItemCollection itemCollection)
{
    var alreadySeen = new Dictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    foreach(var type in itemCollection.GetItems<StructuralType>())
    {
        if (!(type is EntityType || type is ComplexType))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (alreadySeen.ContainsKey(type.FullName))
        {
            Error(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "This template does not support types that differ only by case, the types {0} are not supported", type.FullName));
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alreadySeen.Add(type.FullName, true);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
#>
```

Comment: FYI, the EF6 template is very different from the EF4 template which is why I'm posting this here. Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: @AH. That's not a constructive comment. If you post your own question giving details of what you're trying to do and what errors you received, then perhaps I can help you figure out how to solve them.

Comment: I followed what you wrote and got several errors when running the custom tool.

Answer (score 9):

I've had great success using a NuGet package called PropertyChanged.Fody to get INPC implemented on the entity classes. Just install the package, then add the [ImplementPropertyChanged] attribute to any class and PropertyChanged.Fody will "inject" INPC into the class as part of the build process.  For example if you have a generated entity class called Customer, just add the following code somewhere in your project.

```
using PropertyChanged;

[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public partial class Customer
{
}
```

There are other attributes you can use to control the behavior of the PropertyChanged package.  See https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged for details.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that whenever I do this I use a separate dedicated project/assembly for the EF classes.  That way Fody can weave the INPC stuff into the assembly before the dependent projects need it.

Answer (score 5):

I also had problems. Here's my implementation that works with 6.1.2. Clearly the problem with this solution is that each change in EF is going to require a new tt script. Perhaps Microsoft could provide different options that provide different levels of support.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@ 
 output extension=".cs"#><#

const string inputFile = @"Model.edmx";
var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
var ef = new MetadataTools(this);
var typeMapper = new TypeMapper(code, ef, textTransform.Errors);
var fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
var itemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
var codeStringGenerator = new CodeStringGenerator(code, typeMapper, ef);

if (!typeMapper.VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(typeMapper.GetAllGlobalItems(itemCollection), inputFile))
{
    return string.Empty;
}

WriteHeader(codeStringGenerator, fileManager);

foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false)#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
{
<#
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = typeMapper.GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(entity);
    var collectionNavigationProperties = typeMapper.GetCollectionNavigationProperties(entity);
    var complexProperties = typeMapper.GetComplexProperties(entity);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || collectionNavigationProperties.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public <#=code.Escape(entity)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#> = <#=typeMapper.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(complexProperty)#> = new <#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>
    }

<#
    }

    var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach (var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }

    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach(var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(complexProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }

    var navigationProperties = typeMapper.GetNavigationProperties(entity);
    if (navigationProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            if (navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
            {
#>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
<#
            }
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            WhenPropertyChanged(e);
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    partial void WhenPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    #endregion
}
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}

foreach (var complex in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<ComplexType>(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(complex.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false, includeCollections: false)#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#>
{
<#
    var complexProperties = typeMapper.GetComplexProperties(complex);
    var propertiesWithDefaultValues = typeMapper.GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(complex);

    if (propertiesWithDefaultValues.Any() || complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>
    public <#=code.Escape(complex)#>()
    {
<#
        foreach (var edmProperty in propertiesWithDefaultValues)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#> = <#=typeMapper.CreateLiteral(edmProperty.DefaultValue)#>;
<#
        }

        foreach (var complexProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
        this.<#=code.Escape(complexProperty)#> = new <#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(complexProperty.TypeUsage)#>();
<#
        }
#>
    }

<#
    }

    var simpleProperties = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(complex);
    if (simpleProperties.Any())
    {
        foreach(var edmProperty in simpleProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }

    if (complexProperties.Any())
    {
#>

<#
        foreach(var edmProperty in complexProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.Property(edmProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>
}
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}

foreach (var enumType in typeMapper.GetEnumItemsToGenerate(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(enumType.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false, includeCollections: false)#>
<#
    if (typeMapper.EnumIsFlags(enumType))
    {
#>
[Flags]
<#
    }
#>
<#=codeStringGenerator.EnumOpening(enumType)#>
{
<#
    var foundOne = false;

    foreach (MetadataItem member in typeMapper.GetEnumMembers(enumType))
    {
        foundOne = true;
#>
    <#=code.Escape(typeMapper.GetEnumMemberName(member))#> = <#=typeMapper.GetEnumMemberValue(member)#>,
<#
    }

    if (foundOne)
    {
        this.GenerationEnvironment.Remove(this.GenerationEnvironment.Length - 3, 1);
    }
#>
}
<#
    EndNamespace(code);
}

fileManager.Process();

#>
<#+

public void WriteHeader(CodeStringGenerator codeStringGenerator, EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager fileManager)
{
    fileManager.StartHeader();
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1")#>
//
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2")#>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3")#>
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: true)#>
<#+
    fileManager.EndBlock();
}

public void BeginNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    var codeNamespace = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeNamespace))
    {
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(codeNamespace)#>
{
<#+
        PushIndent("    ");
    }
}

public void EndNamespace(CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(code.VsNamespaceSuggestion()))
    {
        PopIndent();
#>
}
<#+
    }
}

public const string TemplateId = "CSharp_DbContext_Types_EF6";

public class CodeStringGenerator
{
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly TypeMapper _typeMapper;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public CodeStringGenerator(CodeGenerationTools code, TypeMapper typeMapper, MetadataTools ef)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(typeMapper, "typeMapper");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");

        _code = code;
        _typeMapper = typeMapper;
        _ef = ef;
    }

    public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        StringBuilder propertyCode = new StringBuilder();
        propertyCode.AppendFormat("private {0} _{1};",_typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage), _code.Escape(edmProperty));
        propertyCode.AppendFormat(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get{{ return _{2};}} {4}set{{if(_{2} != value){{_{2} = value; OnPropertyChanged(\"{2}\");}}}}}}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));

        return propertyCode.ToString();
    }

    public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
    {
        var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
            navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
            _code.Escape(navProp),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
    }

    public string AccessibilityAndVirtual(string accessibility)
    {
        return accessibility + (accessibility != "private" ? " virtual" : "");
    }

    public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2} : INotifyPropertyChanged{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(", ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }

    public string EnumOpening(SimpleType enumType)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} enum {1} : {2}",
            Accessibility.ForType(enumType),
            _code.Escape(enumType),
            _code.Escape(_typeMapper.UnderlyingClrType(enumType)));
        }

    public void WriteFunctionParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction, Action<string, string, string, string> writeParameter)
    {
        var parameters = FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
        foreach (var parameter in parameters.Where(p => p.NeedsLocalVariable))
        {
            var isNotNull = parameter.IsNullableOfT ? parameter.FunctionParameterName + ".HasValue" : parameter.FunctionParameterName + " != null";
            var notNullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\", " + parameter.FunctionParameterName + ")";
            var nullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\", typeof(" + TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(parameter.RawClrTypeName) + "))";
            writeParameter(parameter.LocalVariableName, isNotNull, notNullInit, nullInit);
        }
    }

    public string ComposableFunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} IQueryable<{1}> {2}({3})",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForMethod(edmFunction)),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
            _code.Escape(edmFunction),
            string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(p.FunctionParameterType) + " " + p.FunctionParameterName).ToArray()));
    }

    public string ComposableCreateQuery(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<{0}>(\"[{1}].[{2}]({3})\"{4});",
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
            edmFunction.NamespaceName,
            edmFunction.Name,
            string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.EsqlParameterName).ToArray()),
            _code.StringBefore(", ", string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray())));
    }

    public string FunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
        var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

        var paramList = String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(p.FunctionParameterType) + " " + p.FunctionParameterName).ToArray());
        if (includeMergeOption)
        {
            paramList = _code.StringAfter(paramList, ", ") + "MergeOption mergeOption";
        }

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2}({3})",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForMethod(edmFunction)),
            returnType == null ? "int" : "ObjectResult<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
            _code.Escape(edmFunction),
            paramList);
    }

    public string ExecuteFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
        var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

        var callParams = _code.StringBefore(", ", String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray()));
        if (includeMergeOption)
        {
            callParams = ", mergeOption" + callParams;
        }

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction{0}(\"{1}\"{2});",
            returnType == null ? "" : "<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
            edmFunction.Name,
            callParams);
    }

    public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} virtual DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
            _code.Escape(entitySet));
    }

    public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
    {
        return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
            ? string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}using System;" + Environment.NewLine + 
                "using System.ComponentModel;{1}" +
                "{2}",
                inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
                includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
                inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
            : "";
    }
}

public class TypeMapper
{
    private const string ExternalTypeNameAttributeName = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration:ExternalTypeName";

    private readonly System.Collections.IList _errors;
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public TypeMapper(CodeGenerationTools code, MetadataTools ef, System.Collections.IList errors)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");
        ArgumentNotNull(errors, "errors");

        _code = code;
        _ef = ef;
        _errors = errors;
    }

    public static string FixNamespaces(string typeName)
    {
        return typeName.Replace("System.Data.Spatial.", "System.Data.Entity.Spatial.");
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace: null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, isNullable: null, modelNamespace: null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, isNullable: null, modelNamespace: modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, bool? isNullable, string modelNamespace)
    {
        if (edmType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var collectionType = edmType as CollectionType;
        if (collectionType != null)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ICollection<{0}>", GetTypeName(collectionType.TypeUsage, modelNamespace));
        }

        var typeName = _code.Escape(edmType.MetadataProperties
                                .Where(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName)
                                .Select(p => (string)p.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
            ?? (modelNamespace != null && edmType.NamespaceName != modelNamespace ?
                _code.CreateFullName(_code.EscapeNamespace(edmType.NamespaceName), _code.Escape(edmType)) :
                _code.Escape(edmType));

        if (edmType is StructuralType)
        {
            return typeName;
        }

        if (edmType is SimpleType)
        {
            var clrType = UnderlyingClrType(edmType);
            if (!IsEnumType(edmType))
            {
                typeName = _code.Escape(clrType);
            }

            typeName = FixNamespaces(typeName);

            return clrType.IsValueType && isNullable == true ?
                String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Nullable<{0}>", typeName) :
                typeName;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("edmType");
    }

    public Type UnderlyingClrType(EdmType edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        var primitiveType = edmType as PrimitiveType;
        if (primitiveType != null)
        {
            return primitiveType.ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        if (IsEnumType(edmType))
        {
            return GetEnumUnderlyingType(edmType).ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        return typeof(object);
    }

    public object GetEnumMemberValue(MetadataItem enumMember)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumMember, "enumMember");

        var valueProperty = enumMember.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
        return valueProperty == null ? null : valueProperty.GetValue(enumMember, null);
    }

    public string GetEnumMemberName(MetadataItem enumMember)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumMember, "enumMember");

        var nameProperty = enumMember.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
        return nameProperty == null ? null : (string)nameProperty.GetValue(enumMember, null);
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetEnumMembers(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        var membersProperty = enumType.GetType().GetProperty("Members");
        return membersProperty != null 
            ? (System.Collections.IEnumerable)membersProperty.GetValue(enumType, null)
            : Enumerable.Empty<MetadataItem>();
    }

    public bool EnumIsFlags(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        var isFlagsProperty = enumType.GetType().GetProperty("IsFlags");
        return isFlagsProperty != null && (bool)isFlagsProperty.GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public bool IsEnumType(GlobalItem edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        return edmType.GetType().Name == "EnumType";
    }

    public PrimitiveType GetEnumUnderlyingType(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        return (PrimitiveType)enumType.GetType().GetProperty("UnderlyingType").GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public string CreateLiteral(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(TimeSpan))
        {
            return _code.CreateLiteral(value);
        }

        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "new TimeSpan({0})", ((TimeSpan)value).Ticks);
    }

    public bool VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(IEnumerable<string> types, string sourceFile)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(types, "types");
        ArgumentNotNull(sourceFile, "sourceFile");

        var hash = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (types.Any(item => !hash.Add(item)))
        {
            _errors.Add(
                new CompilerError(sourceFile, -1, -1, "6023",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_CaseInsensitiveTypeConflict"))));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SimpleType> GetEnumItemsToGenerate(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return GetItemsToGenerate<SimpleType>(itemCollection)
            .Where(e => IsEnumType(e));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToGenerate<T>(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection) where T: EdmType
    {
        return itemCollection
            .OfType<T>()
            .Where(i => !i.MetadataProperties.Any(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName))
            .OrderBy(i => i.Name);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllGlobalItems(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return itemCollection
            .Where(i => i is EntityType || i is ComplexType || i is EntityContainer || IsEnumType(i))
            .Select(g => GetGlobalItemName(g));
    }

    public string GetGlobalItemName(GlobalItem item)
    {
        if (item is EdmType)
        {
            return ((EdmType)item).Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((EntityContainer)item).Name;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type && p.DefaultValue != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type && p.DefaultValue != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetCollectionNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type && np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
    }

    public FunctionParameter GetReturnParameter(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmFunction, "edmFunction");

        var returnParamsProperty = edmFunction.GetType().GetProperty("ReturnParameters");
        return returnParamsProperty == null
            ? edmFunction.ReturnParameter
            : ((IEnumerable<FunctionParameter>)returnParamsProperty.GetValue(edmFunction, null)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public bool IsComposable(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmFunction, "edmFunction");

        var isComposableProperty = edmFunction.GetType().GetProperty("IsComposableAttribute");
        return isComposableProperty != null && (bool)isComposableProperty.GetValue(edmFunction, null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<FunctionImportParameter> GetParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        return FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
    }

    public TypeUsage GetReturnType(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        var returnParam = GetReturnParameter(edmFunction);
        return returnParam == null ? null : _ef.GetElementType(returnParam.TypeUsage);
    }

    public bool GenerateMergeOptionFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var returnType = GetReturnType(edmFunction);
        return !includeMergeOption && returnType != null && returnType.EdmType.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType;
    }
}

public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(T arg, string name) where T : class
{
    if (arg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

Peronally I have some troubles with Fody's implementation maybe this post could help you [T4 Personalization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590165)

**NOTE:** It Works with EF 6.1 to.